# UserControl that embeds another user control, how to access embedded form fields?

Tags: user-controls

I have a long form that the user has to fill out.

So I broke the form into logical units and created another user control for some elements (they will be reused elsewhere).

So say the form has these fields:

UserControl3.ascx

Username
password
email    -- usercontrol2.ascx
address    -- usercontrol2.ascx
city    -- usercontrol2.ascx
state    -- usercontrol2.ascx

So now in the codebehidn of usercontrol3.ascx, how will I access the usercontrol2.ascx's fields so I can write to the db?

Comment: Where is usercontrol2 in relation to user control 3?

Comment: as in the file system? same folder.

Answer (score 1):

if user control 3 contains user control 2, I would modify the code for user control 2 to expose public properties for the information that you need to retreive.

*edit*
There are other ways of doing it, but the property route is the safest route, and avoids strong dependencies between the two controls.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works, but it is just not elegant:

```
Dim txtBox as TextBox = Ctype(parentControl.Controls(Index), System.Web.UI.Controls.TextBox)
stringVariable = txtBox.Text
```

The correct way to do it is to implement properties for your parentControl that access child's controls properties.

```
Public Property AddressField() as string
  Set(byval value as string)
    txtAddressField.Text = value
  End Set
  Get
    Return txtAddressField.Text
  End Get
End Property
```